# How to set CSS attributes relative to a parent node?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code:

```
.over_center {
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
left:50%;
height: 160px; /* two thirds (2/3) of parent size */
width: 160px; /* two thirds (2/3) of parent size */
margin-top: -80px; /* negative one third of parent size */
margin-left: -80px; /* negative one third of parent size */
line-height: 160px; /* two thirds (2/3) of player size */
text-align: center;
}
```

as you can see, I have comments to remind me that the values in these places should be relative to the parent size, which may vary (but is always square, width=height).

obviously I can use js to style these accordingly, but I believe it will be much cleaner if there was a way to do so directly in CSS.

Comment: ahhhh but there is a catch :-). first four lines work okay. line-height should be relative to the parent width attribute, so percentage doesnt do what I wanted in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of them, you can use percentages:

```
.over_center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 66.66%;       /* Relative to containing block's height */
    width: 66.66%;        /* Relative to containing block's width */
    margin-top: -33.33%;  /* Relative to containing block's width */
    margin-left: -33.33%; /* Relative to containing block's width */
    line-height: 160px;   /* Problem here */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Note it won't work if the parent element isn't the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details). In this case, since it has `position: absolute`, the containing block is established by the nearest non statically positioned ancestor.

For `line-height` (and the other properties in case the parent isn't the containing block), you have some options:

- Use JavaScript
- Use Server side scripting
- Use CSS preprocessor
- Use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). Warning: experimental feature, negligible browser support.

Answer (score 2):

Due to how absolute positioning works, this will depend on what your parent element is.

If the parent element has `position: relative`, then this parent element is your element's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details), and you can simply use percentages for most of these, just as you have done with the `top` and `left` properties:

```
height: 66%;
width: 66%;
margin-top: -33%;
margin-left: -33%;
```

All of these percentages excluding `height` (but including `margin-top`) are relative to the containing block width, but since you know it's always a square, it's not going to be a problem for you.

`line-height` is a bit different: its values are usually relative to the font size. If you need it to be relative to the height you'll have to hardcode the absolute value yourself. At least you'll only have one value that needs to be updated should the parent's dimensions change.

If the parent element doesn't have `position: relative`, then the containing block is elsewhere and you won't be able to use percentages with *any* of these properties. You'll have to hardcode the values then.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way in CSS, but you could use something like LESS:

```
@parser: 240px;
.over_center {
    height: @parser * 2 / 3;
    width: @parser * 2 / 3;
    margin-top: @parser / -3;
    margin-left: @parser / -3;
    line-height: @parser * 2 / 3;
}
```

In this way, you just have to change a single value to affect everything.